# .NET LINQ IQueryable: what is `Expression` for?

Tags: .net, linq, iqueryable

I'm working on a LINQ provider so am implementing IQueryable.

What is the purpose of the `Expression` property within this interface? I normally just return something like `Expression.Constant(this)` from my implementations, but have no idea if that's bad.

Bizarrely the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc679627%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) states "This allows the framework to differentiate between LINQ and Entity SQL queries".

Comment: Try looking what is present in EF or LINQ-to-SQL in that property...

Comment: As i remember `Expression` property holds expression for current `IQueryable` as we can have a chain of them, so each `IQueryable` has his own and previously grouped expressions. But i might be wrong, as i use it a long time ago.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Yeah I'm aware that that is one possible way of using it but as far as I'm aware there's no requirement of the framework to use it that way. So is this property for implementers to do with as they please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IQueryable.Expression` member is fed back to the `IQueryProvider` by all the various `Queryable.*` "operators" (`.Where()`, `.Select()`, `.Join()`, ...), like:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) {
    if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>( 
        Expression.Call(
            null,
            ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource)), 
            new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate) }
            ));
}
```

(taken from the [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,62))

Normally it should be the whole expression.

Clearly no one will kill you if you pass directly a whole reference to your `IQueryable` class through the `Expression.Constant()`, but I do think that this isn't "kosher".

The point of putting the "real" expression in `Expression` (like it is done by the `Enumerable.AsQueryable()`, by EF and by LINQ-to-SQL, just to name three `IQueryable` providers) is that other external classes can freely analyze and manipulate the `Expression` and feed it back to the provider in the same way that the `Queryable.Where` does, so doing

```
Expression expression = source.Expression;
// here "expression" is manipulated
return source.Provider.CreateQuery<SomeType>(expression);
```

To give an example... There are some "query fixer"s that modify the query like https://github.com/davidfowl/QueryInterceptor (a generic modifier for queries), or https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler, that permits to do:

```
var employees = (from employee in db.Employees
                 where employee.FullName == "Test User"
                 select employee).Decompile().ToList();
```

where `FullName` **isn't** mapped in the DB, and is a property like:

```
class Employee
{
    [Computed]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }
```

(with `FirstName` and `LastName` mapped to the db). *DelegateDecompiler* takes the `Expression` from the `IQueryable`, searches for properties that have the `Computed` attribute, decompiles them and places the decompiled code (converted to an expression tree) back in the `IQueryable.Expression` (though the use of `IQueryable.Provider.CreateQuery()`)

If you want to save additional data, you can put it in the `Provider`: you can generate a new instance of the `IQueryProvider` class in the `CreateQuery` method. That too is fed back by the `Queryable.*` operators (because the `CreateQuery<>` is an instance method of `source.Provider`)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. As a small follow up question, is it relatively common to use the Expression property to attempt to modify, duplicate or otherwise inspect the queries? I've never seen this done in practice, and would assume this is a very unknown 'feature'.

Comment: Oh and my implementation does expose other properties which allow inspection of the configured query, so `Expression.Constant(this)` isn't as daft as it might first seem.

Comment: @IanNewson I would say that it is rare in programmers, uncommon in library writers.